# Is there any way to have a projection without size changing?

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

Blender implements an othogonal projection so the further is an object, the smallest it is. In my case, I would like to get a plane (x-z p.e.) where the feel of depth is lost so if 2 objects have the same size, no matter how far they are between each other that they are going to be seen as of the same size, even if one is centered in the image and the other one is far away. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Maybe set camera to 'orthographic' for renders or press Numpad 5 for preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to switch your camera lens to Orthographic:
[image]

You can get the same effect for your 3D view (not a camera) by pressing 5 on Numpad.

Comment: Yes, I saw it with the Cebbi's comment. Just one thing about this: If an object is further than a defined point, I lose from vision but if it is nearer than this point, I can see it of the same size although is far than other objects. How can I change this? Playing with sensor? Depth of field?

Comment: Play with (increase) the Clipping distance... you can see the input fields on the right on the screenshot.